# Prove that $[0,1]$ is not a connected subset of a discrete metric space.

Tags: real-analysis

Given: Prove that $[0,1]$ is not a connected subset of the discrete metric space

In discrete metric space, $(a,b], [a,b), (a,b),$ and $[a,b]$ are both open and closed. I'd use the theorem 1: Let $(X,p)$ be a metric space and $E \subset X$. It's impossible that $E=E_1 \cup E_2,$ and $E_1,E_2 < E$, and $E_2$ intersects closure of $E_1$= empty set.

my prove: Suppose $E=[0,1]$. It's possible that $E= E_1 \cup E_2$, and $E_1$ intersects closure of $E_2$ is empty set. To show, ....

I am lost. I need help

please

Comment: What if $E_1=\left[0,\frac12\right)$ and $E_2$ is the rest of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Since E1 intersects closure of E2 is not 1/2 and closure of E1 intersects E2 is empty set, we can conclude that it's impossible that [0,1] is E1 U E2 and E1 intersects closure of E2 is empty set. Thus, [0,1] is not a connected subset of a discrete metric space. is this correct? or no? if not, then could you help with more explanation? cause im trying to understand. if i cant understand, could you at least show me how to prove it? I am not just looking for an answer.

Comment: $E_1$ does *not* intersect the closure of $E_2$. $E_2=\left[\frac12,1\right]$, which by hypothesis is a closed set. So is $E_1$. Thus, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint, non-empty, closed sets whose union is $[0,1]$. Therefore ... ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note** : In a discrete space , every set is both open and closed. (Therefore closure of each set is itself).

Now,
$[0,1] = [0,0.5) U [0.5,1]$

These two sets in the RHS are disjoint.
Thus $[0,1]$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

In the discrete space, every set is an open set. Take for example the singleton $\{0\}$ is open. You also have that $(0, 1]$ is open...